# How can I make correctly sized images to use in my android app

Tags: android, image

I have an image that I want to use in my app but I want it to look good on multiple devices, which is the reason there are many drawable folders (hpdi, xhpdi etc etc).

My image is just one size 170 x 80 px. Is there a tool I can use to generate appropriately sized versions of this image to place in my drawable folders?

Also, on a side note. If I were to set the 170x80 px  image as the source of an image button. Do I set the width and height to wrap_content or do I set it to 170 and 80 dp?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one image and copy it in your `drawables` folder, the android framework assumes it is **mdpi** and automatically scales it up or down if you don't provide the others.

To answer your last question, you should set `layout_width` and `layout_height` of your image in the layout to `wrap content` then. You also should not assume that 170px look the same as 170dp.

convert from dp to pixels:

> px = dp * (dpi / 160)

convert from pixels to dp:

> dp = px / (dpi / 160)

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html) is a very useful article about how to support different devices on android

Answer (score 0):

The [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) can generate images for you in different dpi formats.